# why should i add two backslash to this string?

Tags: ios, string, swift

am working on a weather app and this question jump in my mind

original string

```
<span class="phrase">
```

string with backslash

```
"<span class=\"phrase\">"
```

Comment: try: "<span class=\'phrase\'>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double quotes to open and close the string. If you have a double quote halfway, the parser will think that the string ends there. Adding the backslash ('escaping' the quote) tells the parser that the quote should be interpreted as a literal quote within the string rather than a string terminator.

For more information see [Swift: strings and characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) (scroll down to 'Special Characters in String Literals').

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is used as an [escape character](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID295) - a `"` in a string literal means 'end of the string' in Swift, so you need another character - the backslash - to tell Swift 'interpret this `"` literally - I want it to be part of the string.'.

Of course, in HTML you can specify the value of an attribute with a single quote as well, so

```
"<span class=\"phrase\">"
```

and

```
"<span class='phrase'>"
```

will have the same effect.